# req.session keeps returning undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session, cookies

I am new to cookies and session in express and I have a problem I don't understand how to solve. I make a simple user login system which communicate with DB. My login call works fine, but when I try to recuperate the value in `req.session.user`, it always return undefined when I call it in `/getevents` or `/addevent`.

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const saltRounds = 10;

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  session({
    key:"userId",
    secret: "123123123",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  }));

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  database: 'defaultdb',
  host: "dbhost.com",
  port: 12345,
  user: "db_user",
  password: "password"
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  db.query(
    "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?;",
    [username],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({ err: err });
      }


      if (result.length > 0) {
        bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password, (error, response) => {
          if (response) {
            req.session.userId = result[0].id;
            res.send(result);
          } else {
            res.send({ message: "Invalid username / password !" });
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.send({ message: "Username does not exist !" });
      }
    }
  );
});

app.get("/getevents", (req, res) => {
      db.query(
      "SELECT title, date FROM events WHERE user_id =?;",
      req.session.userId,
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        else {
          res.send(result);
        }
      }
    );
});

app.post("/addevent", (req, res) => {
  db.query(
    "INSERT INTO event (title,date,user_id) VALUES (" + req.body.title + ", " + req.body.date + ", " + parseInt(req.session.userId) + ")",
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    }
  );
})
```

After trying to resolve for a few hours I'm kind of out of ideas...

Comment: It would help to learn a little more about how you're testing this: Browser or e.g. Postman? What's shown in the network tab, any CORS issues shown when it tries to return the cookie to you?

Comment: @JoschaGötzer I tested with postman and overall the only issue is when I call getevents or addevent where req.session.userId return undefined. I observed however that in login's db.query when I insert a value in req.session.userId it's there. But if I look again right at the end of the call, req.sesdion.userId is undefined...

Comment: Important to note /login sets the userId if the call is succesful and then /getevents should be able to recuperate it.